# VSTS rollback if any one task fails in the build process

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to rollback to the previous commit state of that particular task if any of the task fails in the build process.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How To by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194956(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You want gated checkins: [Use a gated check-in build process to validate changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631(v=vs.120).aspx). This way, it's not possible for someone to checkout the changeset with the broken code.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are using Git as VCS

There are two options  fir you situation.

- **Option 1:** Use **Pull Request validation** (recommend)

  Instead of commit change on the branch (assume it's `master` branch) directly, you can apply changes via pull request. And you can use pull request validation before merging changes into `master` branch.

  You can create a branch (such as `dev` branch) from `master` branch, and commit and push changes to `dev` branch. Then add branch policy (build validation) on master branch. Then if there has pull request to merge changes into `master` branch, the PR validation will be triggered.

  [image]
- **Option 2:** **Reset the commit and force push** to VSTS git repo

  If you want to commit changes on the branch (`master`) directly instead of using pull request, you can reset the commit by below commands:

  ```
  git checkout master #if HEAD is not point to master branch
  git reset --hard HEAD~
  git push -f
  ```

  Now `master` branch is rollback to the pervious commit.

#### If you are using TFVC as VCS

You can use [**Gated Checkin**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers?view=vsts#gated) which will validate the build before checkin.